# Go regexp: finding next item after an occurence

Tags: regex, go

I'm a Go beginner and I've been playing with regexes. Example:

```
r, _ := regexp.Compile(`\* \* \*`)
r2 := r.ReplaceAll(b, []byte("<hr>"))
```

(Replace all `* * *`s for `<hr>`s)

One thing that I have no idea how to do is to find the `next` item after an occurence. In JavaScript/jQuery I used to do this:

```
$("#input-content p:has(br)").next('p').doStuff()
```

(Find the next `p` `tag` after a `p` tag that has a `br` tag inside).

What's the simplest way to accomplish the same in Go? Say, finding the next line after `* * *` ?

> ```
> * * *
>
> Match this line
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use a capturing group to grap the contents of that sentence:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "regexp"

func main() {

    str := `
* * *

Match this line
`   
    r, _ := regexp.Compile(`\* \* \*\n.*\n(.*)`)

    fmt.Println(r.FindStringSubmatch(str)[1])
}
```

**Output:**

```
Match this line
```

**Explanation:**

```
\* \* \*    Matches the first line containing the asterisks.
\n          A newline.
.*          Second line. Can be anything (Likely the line is simply empty)
\n          A newline
(           Start of capturing group
.*          The content of interest
)           End of capturing group
```

---

In comments you asked how to replace the third line by `<hr/>`. In this case I would use two capturing groups - one for the part before the line of interest and one for the line itself. In the replacement pattern you can then use `$1` to use the value of the first capturing group in the result.

Example:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "regexp"

func main() {

    str := `
* * * 

Match this line
`   
    r, _ := regexp.Compile(`(\* \* \*\n.*\n)(.*)`)

    str = string(r.ReplaceAll([]byte(str), []byte("$1<hr/>")))

    fmt.Println(str)
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks it worked. Just one question. I used `r.ReplaceAll(b, []byte("<hr>"))` instead but even the `* * *` was replaced. Does this have to do with the `[1]` part in your code? If so, how to update my code so that `* * *` is not replaced?